# Not able to pass 'date' header in ajax jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, jquery-ajax

We are not able to see in the request headers. Does not seem like a server issue. It is mostly from the client side/browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
       
    $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        headers: {'date': (new Date()).toUTCString()},
        success: function(returnhtml){
            $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
            $("#loadingimg").hide();                    
        }           
    });    
    
});
```

[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I31U.png)

http://jsfiddle.net/ddtxra/60wme3pf/

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) as:

> Date is listed in the forbidden header names in the fetch spec - so this code will not send Date header

Where the [fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name) lists reserved names:

> A forbidden header name is a header name that is a byte-case-insensitive match for one of
>
> `Accept-Charset`
> `Accept-Encoding`
> `Access-Control-Request-Headers`
> `Access-Control-Request-Method`
> `Connection`
> `Content-Length`
> `Cookie`
> `Cookie2`
> `Date`
> `DNT`
> `Expect`
> `Host`
> `Keep-Alive`
> `Origin`
> `Referer` *[sic]*
> `TE`
> `Trailer`
> `Transfer-Encoding`
> `Upgrade`
> `Via`

Use a different header name, but not one of the other reserved header names and your fiddle (with *your* code added) works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/19yjdft5/

Comment: Just wondering, as per the forbidden header names, those will not be modified. It seems like browser includes them automatically. But why it is not for 'Date' header. 'Date' seems like one of the unique forbidden headers which does not get sent automatically.